# Program for this number pattern using for loop in java 1 22 3 4444 5 666666 7 88888888. Not getting the desired pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int noOfRows = 8;

    printPattern(noOfRows);
}

private static void printPattern(int num){
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(i);
        }            
        System.out.println();            
    }
```

Program for this number pattern using for loop in java 1 22 3 4444 5 666666 7 88888888. Not getting the desired pattern

Comment: There is no code addressing the (presumed though not spelled out) condition that if a line is odd, then one digit should be printed, otherwise `i` digits should be printed.

Comment: this looks like homework. please read [asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250) and [edit] your question if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to print odd numbers once, so add a `break`

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j<=i;j++){
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i % 2 == 1) 
            break;
    }            
    System.out.println();            
}
```

**output**

```
1
22
3
4444
5
666666
7
88888888
```

Comment: Add formatting to show the real output of the code, which is not exactly as requested. Close enough for up-vote, though.

Comment: Can also be done as a single statement in Java 11+: `System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8).mapToObj(i -> Integer.toString(i).repeat((i & 1) == 1 ? 1 : i)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));` --- If you want to obscure it a bit, replace `repeat(...)` call with `repeat((((i & 1) << 1) - 1) & i))`.

Comment: so, `(i & 1) == 1` rather than `(i % 2 == 1)` ?

Comment: Bit math is faster than division math, not that it matters for this code. --- Obscure version might be faster still, even though it has more math operations, because it doesn't generate jump instructions. I liked the obscure version since to look funny. --- None of that really matters anyway, since the performance of streams is less than optimal.